# Randint not specified, even though it worked beforehand - Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a section of coding, which is this bit

```
def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)
from time import sleep, time
BUB_CHANCE = 10
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while True:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y
```

where it says if `randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:`, apparently `randint` is not defined, even though I had previously used it in the same code.

Can someone please tell me why this is an error? I have only been using python for a few days :/

Comment: Did you import it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
from random import randint
```

at the top of your code, or:

```
from numpy.random import randint
```

if you are using `numpy`.

Docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html